# ASP.NET MVC multiple threads access database simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a ASP.NET MVC 4 app using Entity Framework where multiple threads can access a table at the same time (add, delete row, etc.) Right now I am doing `using (UserDBContext db = new UserDBContext())` within each controller (so a new `DBContext` is created for each request since MVC framework creates a seperate thread for each request). From what i read, this is safe; however, I am curious about:

1. What happens when two threads access the same table, but not the same row? Are both threads allowed to access simultaneously?
2. What happens when two threads modify the same *row*? say, one tries to read while the other tries to delete? Is one thread blocked (put to sleep), then gets waken up automatically when the other is done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: Locking in the database. Guaranteeing multi user scenarios is one of the top priority of databases. Learn the basics. There are good books.

2: Locking. Again. One will have to wait.

This is extremely fundamental so I would suggest you take 2 steps back and get something like "SQL for dummies" and learn about ACID conditions that any decent database guarantees. NOTHING in here has to do with EF by the way. This is all done on the database internal level.

Comment: +3: Optimistic concurrency